# Catch a deserialization exception before a ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Here is a problem: I have a controller that takes an input model. Lets say

```
public class AppUserUpdateData {

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
  protected String login;  
  @JsonDeserialize(using = MyDateTimeDeserializer.class)  
  protected Date startWorkDate;
  *************
  other properties and methods
  *************
}
```

The problem is when I want to restrict a down board of a date I eventually get an HTTP exception 400 without any messages despite I handle this case in my code!
here is a controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(
      value = "/users/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  public @ResponseBody AbstractSuccessResult updateUser(@PathVariable Long userId,
      @RequestBody AppUserUpdateData  appUserUpdateRequest, HttpServletRequest request) {    
    AbstractSuccessResult response = new AbstractSuccessResult();
    appUserService.updateUser(appUserUpdateRequest, userId);
    return response;
  }
```

Here is a Deserializer:

```
public class MyDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

  @Override
  public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    try {
      return DataTypeHelper.stringToDateTime(jsonParser.getText());
    } catch (MyOwnWrittenException ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
  }  
}
```

In a `DataTypeHelper.stringToDateTime` are some validations that are blocking invalid date-strings. 
And there is a handler for a my exception:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler({ MyOwnWrittenException .class})
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidRequest(RuntimeException exc, 
    WebRequest request) {

    MyOwnWrittenException ex = (MyOwnWrittenException) exc;
    BasicErrorMessage message; = new BasicErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());    
    AbstractUnsuccessfulResult result = new AbstractUnsuccessfulResult(message);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return handleExceptionInternal(exc, result, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
  }
}
```

The problem is that when an exception in a `MyDateTimeDeserializer` has been thrown it doesn't falling into a `MyExceptionHandler` but I cannot understand why? What am I doing wrong?
In the response is just an empty response with a code 400(

**UPD**
Thanks to @Joe Doe's answer the problem has been solved. Here is my updated handler:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)    
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler({ MyOwnWrittenException .class})
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidRequest(RuntimeException exc, 
    WebRequest request) {

    MyOwnWrittenException ex = (MyOwnWrittenException) exc;
    BasicErrorMessage message; = new BasicErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());    
    AbstractUnsuccessfulResult result = new AbstractUnsuccessfulResult(message);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return handleExceptionInternal(exc, result, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
  }

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
      HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
    String message = null;
    if (cause instanceof JsonMappingException) {
      if (cause.getCause() instanceof MyOwnWrittenException) {
        return handleInvalidRequest((RuntimeException) cause.getCause(), request);
      } else {
        message = cause.getMessage();
      }
    } else {
      message = ex.getMessage();
    }
    AbstractUnsuccessfulResult result = new AbstractUnsuccessfulResult(
        new BasicErrorMessage(message));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, result, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
  }
}
```

**UPD**
In my project it doesn't work without annotation `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` 
I believe that is because of number of ControllerAdvices in a project

Comment: Can you please also post `MyOwnWrittenException`, `BasicErrorMessage` and `AbstractUnsuccessfulResult`? Furthermore I think you have over-complicated things without much need to do so, but please post the above to check on your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before `updateUser` in your controller gets invoked, its arguments have to be resolved. This is where `HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite` comes in, and delegates to one of pre-registered `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`s - in this particular case it delegates to `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`.

By delegating I mean calling the resolver's `resolveArgument` method. This method indirectly calls the `deserialize` method from your deserializer, which throws an exception of type `MyOwnWrittenException`. The problem is that this exception gets wrapped in another exception. In fact, by the time it propagates back to `resolveArgument`, it's of type `HttpMessageNotReadableException`.

So, rather than catching `MyOwnWrittenException` in your custom exception handler, you need to catch exceptions of type `HttpMessageNotReadableException`. Then, in the method that handles that case, you can check whether the "original" exception was in fact `MyOwnWrittenException` - you can do that by repeatedly calling the `getCause` method. In my case (it's probably going to be the same in yours), I needed to call `getCause` twice to "unwrap" the original exception (`HttpMessageNotReadableException` -> `JsonMappingException` -> `MyOwnWrittenException`).

Note that you can't simply substitute `MyOwnWrittenException` with `HttpMessageNotReadableException` in your exception handler since it clashes (at runtime) with another method, specifically designed to handle exceptions of the latter type, called `handleHttpMessageNotReadable`.

In summary, you can do something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        // ex.getCause().getCause().getClass() gives MyOwnWrittenException
        // the actual logic that handles the exception...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it has helped! Thank you so much!

Comment: Works! I admit:)